# Facebook Graph API return error when i am getting friends list

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting error from facebook Graph API when i am trying to get the friend list from facebook.

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","code":2}}
```

This are the permissions i added.

```
OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) HomeScreen.this);
List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            permissions.add("email");
            op.setPermissions(permissions);
            Session session = new Session.Builder(HomeScreen.this)
                    .setApplicationId(getResources().getString(R.string.app_id))
                    .build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.openForRead(op);
```

Comment: Maybe some temporary issue. As indicated, you could try again in sometime.

Comment: The above code was working fine but today morning this exception occur.